# How to pass current values to wizard in odoo

Tags: odoo

I have some wizard opens when I click a button, this wizard insert some values in child model of the main model so I need to send some data from main model to the wizard

data includes current id

Comment: Can you please share that wizard opening code ? or that will be done by an action ?

Comment: Can you described more the different steps of the wizard opening ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found a solution 
in python code I used a function like this

```
@api.multi
    def open_wizard(self):
        return {
            'view_type': 'form',
            'view_mode': 'form',
            'res_model': 'model_name',
            'target': 'new',
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'context': {'current_id': self.id}
        }
```

and in wizard I can use this "current_id" like this

```
print self._context['current_id']
```

Comment: this is helpful.

Answer (score 4):

When opening your wizard or creating your wizard. Pass the values in the context like this. I have omitted the other values you would define when starting a wizard, the rest of your code to load the wizard still applies. You must append `default_` in front of the regular field name.

```
'context': "{'default_field1': '%s','default_field2': '%s'}" % (field1_value, field2_value)
```

Comment: I used something like this in python code 
@api.multi
    def open_wizard(self):
        return {
            'view_type': 'form',
            'view_mode': 'form',
            'res_model': 'model_name',
            'target': 'new',
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'context': {'current_id': self.id}
        }

Comment: Hello philip, well you are everywhere on odoo questions..lol..
BTW i want to use cintext in xml odoo10 and want to get the id of active id of the opened record who can I get it here is the code: 
<field name="context">{'default_partner': ("What to do here")}</field>